# How prevent HG Workbench to ask for user name by using subrepositories?

Tags: ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

I use HG Workbench and subrepositories over a ssh connection. I use also ssh-rsa to avoid typing my **password** every time. This works great for the main repository. But if I push or pull HG Workbench (or command shell) promt's with a dialog to typing my **login name** for **every** subreposititory. Can I prevent this?

Update:

I use windows. Also I have a `[ui]` section with `username` in my global `mercurial.ini` and in `hgrc` of  every subrepositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows edit the global `mercurial.ini` settings file and add `ssh` key to the `ui` section:

```
[ui]
ssh = tortoiseplink.exe -l <username>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to use **SSH keys** and follow setup sets by this post: [Set up SSH for Mercurial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial). Key step is to add the following content to mercurial.ini (TortoiseHg’s global setting file):

```
[ui]
# Name data to appear in commits
username = -name-you-want-to-show- <-email-@email.com>
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" - ssh - 2 - batch - C
```

Also, make sure **Pageant.exe** is running in background in order to make it work (`Add key` > `load` > your input passphrase file).

Comment: My mercurial _setup_ is how you described it. Also I have the username in my ```mercurial.ini``` and in all ```hgrc``` files. The ssh line is included for compression and has no effect to my issue. The pull/push for the main repository works. It seems that mercurial forgets the username by requesting the **subrepositories** which are declared in the ```.hgsub``` file (the source of the repositories is a url string without the username). Any idea?

Comment: after playing with tortoiseplink I found the solution: ```ssh = tortoiseplink.exe -l <username>```. thx for the hint

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS you are using, but if you are on Linux the [`hg-ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/hg-ssh.8.html) command ought to work. There's more info on the Mercurial site [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SharedSSH). If you don't get any better answers it might be a good workaround.

Comment: I use windows with putty and pageant. Generated a key and stored it on the servers authorized_keys file. That works for single repositories. But for a subrepository I must enter again my login name?